# Kernel pages that are swappable?

Tags: linux, named-pipes, virtual-memory

(Linux) Kernel pages are not swappable, I know that.

But I recently learned about FIFO (named-pipe) and that it can resides on the disk.

Those FIFOs are in kernel page? So can we say that a kernel page that includes a FIFO **is** swappable?

Are there any other special cases like that?

Answer (score 0):

> When processes are exchanging data
>          via the FIFO, the kernel passes all data internally without writing  it
>          to  the filesystem.  Thus, the FIFO special file has no contents on the
>          filesystem; the filesystem entry merely serves as a reference point  so
>          that processes can access the pipe using a name in the filesystem.

(c) [fifo manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/fifo.7.html)

Nothing ever hits the disc, so we can't say it's being swapped / swappable.